# Create pandas dataframe from a series containing list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series

One of the columns of my pandas dataframe looks like this

```
>> df
    Item 
0   [{"id":A,"value":20},{"id":B,"value":30}]
1   [{"id":A,"value":20},{"id":C,"value":50}]
2   [{"id":A,"value":20},{"id":B,"value":30},{"id":C,"value":40}]
```

I want to expand it as

```
      A      B       C
0     20     30      NaN
1     20     NaN     50
2     20     30      40
```

I tried

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.item[i]).T
    header = df1.iloc[0]
    df1 = df1[1:]
    df1 = df1.rename(columns = header)
    dfx = dfx.append(df1)
```

But this takes a lot of time as my data is huge. What is the best way to do this?

My original json data looks like this:

```
{
  {
   '_id': '5b1284e0b840a768f5545ef6',
   'device': '0035sdf121',
   'customerId': '38',
   'variantId': '31',
   'timeStamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 2, 11, 50, 11),
   'item': [{'id': A, 'value': 20},
          {'id': B, 'value': 30},
          {'id': C, 'value': 50}
  },
  {
   '_id': '5b1284e0b840a768f5545ef6',
   'device': '0035sdf121',
   'customerId': '38',
   'variantId': '31',
   'timeStamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 2, 11, 50, 11),
   'item': [{'id': A, 'value': 20},
            {'id': B, 'value': 30},
            {'id': C, 'value': 50} 
  },
.............
}
```

Comment: You should look at how you are building the DataFrame in the first place.  You should not have those values in the DataFrame.  Can you convert your original data to something that is easy to ingest?

Comment: OK.  Did you research Pandas' `pd.read_json()` command for examples on how to do this cleanly?

Comment: It should be relatively easy to convert the `json` directly to a more appropriate `DataFrame` - can you show a sample of the original data?

Comment: Thanks guys. I have edited the question with the structure of my original json file. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @JeffH, you should really look at how you are constructing the `DataFrame`.

Assuming you are getting this from somewhere out of your control then you can convert to the your desired `DataFrame` with:

```
In []:
pd.DataFrame(df['Item'].apply(lambda r: {d['id']: d['value'] for d in r}).values.tolist())

Out[]:
    A     B     C
0  20  30.0   NaN
1  20   NaN  50.0
2  20  30.0  40.0
```

Comment: How will it change if my dictionary has more than two values? say 'id','value' and 'strength' ??